# Identify recursive formula in method

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I want to write a recursive method "is_segment" that returns `True`if the list at the fist argument contains the contents of the list in the second argument.

It is very easy to check that iterativelly but I want to do it with recursion

I am not sure how to move from the classic `for` loop to the concept of checking the string recursively.

Comment: It seems you have some research and practicing to do.  Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. 
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.
Since you're still stuck at "I am not sure," you need a local tutor, some tutorials and exercises, or simply examples useful to your level of programming and your learning style -- but not Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please add the `for` loop code to your question and maybe someone can point you towards writing a recursive function for that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python: Convert a for loop into a recursion function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21049724/python-convert-a-for-loop-into-a-recursion-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my take on recursion

```py
def is_segment(LST1: list, LST2: list) -> bool:
    """returns True if the list at the fist argument contains the contents of 
        the list in the second argument"""
    # base case
    if not LST2:
        return True  # return True if LST2 is empty

    CHECK = LST2.pop()
    if not CHECK in LST1:
        return False # return False if the element of LST2 is not present in LST1

    return is_segment(LST1, LST2) # check for the remaining LST2 as we popped the element
```

You can just check through inbuilt issubset() method for class set

```py
def is_segment(LST1: list, LST2: list) -> bool:
    """returns True if the list at the fist argument contains the contents of 
        the list in the second argument"""

    return set(LST2).issubset(set(LST1)) # checks if LST2 is a subset of LST1
```